# Interpreting a plot of n confidence intervals for the mean and variance

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

I wanted to know how I would go about interpreting a plot such as this:

[image: Confidence Interval Plot]

where the vertical line segments represent 50 realizations of a confidence interval for $\mu$

How would I explain the location of $\mu$ with regards to the line segments? Assume the lines were more to the left or right of $\mu$, what would that signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plots like this are usually shown in classes to explain the meaning of a $(1-\alpha)\cdot 100\%$ confidence interval for a population parameter $\mu$. Under repeated sampling, they cover $\mu$ in about $(1-\alpha)\cdot 100\%$ of all hypothetical random samples. In your case, only three of 50 intervals are 'wrong', i.e. they lead to wrong conclusions about the position of $\mu$. With larger coverage probability (lower $\alpha$), the intervals would get larger and thus even more of them would cover $\mu$.This illustration also stresses the fact that it's the confidence interval that's random, not the parameter. Note that in reality, you have only one sample, thus one interval, and you don't know the value of $\mu$.

There might be several reasons why the centers of the intervals are not exactly $\mu$ on average:

- Random fluctuation of the corresponding point estimates
- Asymmetric intervals, i.e. the point estimates are not in the middle of the intervals
- Biased estimates of $\mu$